# Error when add firebaseui 2.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I tried use firebase-ui 2.2.0
this is my gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4"

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I got these errors :

```
Error:Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha5
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1
Error:Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha5
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:palette-v7:25.4.0
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0
```

How to solve this?
What is wrong with my gradle ?

Comment: Your errors aren't related to FirebaseUI

Comment: As a matter of fact it is. Without that line, it works well. Looks like FirebaseUI has these as its dependencies, https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the Google maven repo to your top level gradle file. See the link --> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

Answer (score 0):

Firebase UI by itself is having its own set of dependencies

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/build.gradle

These are the dependencies that your error log says is missing.

Looks like you have to add those dependencies locally for the FirebaseUI to work

Comment: so i must insert dependecies needed by firebase ui?

Comment: Unfortunately looks like it